# Angular 5 - Uncaught ReferenceError: req is not defined

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

I recently updated my running project from Angular 4.4.3 to Angular5. I updated all angular packages to Angular 5.0.0 as per the update guide.

Plus I also updated the angular CLI to 1.5.0. Since then I am getting below error in console:

```
polyfills.b8a5e5b….bundle.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: req is not defined
    at polyfills.b8a5e5b….bundle.js:1
    at polyfills.b8a5e5b….bundle.js:1
    at polyfills.b8a5e5b….bundle.js:1
    at Function.r.__load_patch (polyfills.b8a5e5b….bundle.js:1)
    at polyfills.b8a5e5b….bundle.js:1
    at c (polyfills.b8a5e5b….bundle.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (polyfills.b8a5e5b….bundle.js:1)
    at Object.eFQL (polyfills.b8a5e5b….bundle.js:1)
    at n (inline.904a54f….bundle.js:1)
    at Object.TU+8 (polyfills.b8a5e5b….bundle.js:1)
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Most likely a CLI issue, see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8359)

Comment: Update the post with package json

Comment: @Aravind away from my machine, will share the package json soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `node_modules` and run `npm install`.

It works for me.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually just a bug with `uglify-es`.  Update `uglify-es` on your project to `>3.1.8` until it's fixed in the CLI. Got the answer from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8359)

Comment: I am away. Will surely try this when back in another 10-12 hours. Thanks for help!

Comment: Works for me. Although `uglify-es` was part of some other dependency, I just added it explicitly in my `package.json`.

Comment: just checked, I dont even have uglify-es module in my project.

Comment: that makes sense @Manu that's because it's pulled in as part of the cli. As per @pali the reason it may have worked for him is the package pulling in uglify-es may have a `*` or `^` so any clean install after the patch was created would "fix" it.

Comment: Thanks @zmanc I deleted the node_modules folder. Ran npm cache clean and installed the modules again. It worked! Might be caching issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @zmanc What do you mean >3.1.8? 3.1.8 is the latest version as of today.

Comment: @KthProg any of the sub dependencies may be wildcarded which would resolve the issue even though the package itself is unchanged.

Comment: ... That still doesn't explain how I can upgrade to a version of uglify-es that does not exist (there is no version greater than 3.1.8)

Answer (score 2):

The point is your version of CLI has old `uglify-es`. You need CLI in version `1.4.9`.

Works for me:

1. Remove `node_modules` from main project.
2. `npm install` afresh
3. go to `Ctrl+Windows` -> `%appdata%` -> `npm` -> `node_modules` -> `@angular`
4. Remove `cli`
5. Install CLI afresh by `npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.9`

Answer (score 1):

1. Clear npm cache (`npm cache clear --force`)
2. Delete `node_modules`
3. Re-install all packages (`npm install`)
4. Install latest version of `uglify-es` (`npm install uglify-es@latest`)
5. Install `1.6.0-beta.0` or greater version of @angular/cli (globally and locally if you have a local installation [`npm install @angular/cli@1.6.0-beta.0`])
6. Ignore explosion of dependency issues primarily caused by npm packages still catching up with Angular 5
7. No errors, be happy

It's possible that only step 5 is really needed, but I ran every one of these steps and it fixed the issue.